# Issues with time slicing

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I was trying to see the effect of  time slicing. And how it can consume significant amount of time. Actually, I was trying to divide a certain work into number of threads and see the effect.

I have a two core processor. So two threads can run in parallel. I was trying to see if I have a work w that is done by 2 threads, and if I have the same work done by t threads with each thread doing w/t of the work. How much does time slicing play a role in it

As time slicing is time consuming process, I was expecting that when I do the same work using a two thread process or by a t thread process, the amount of time taken by the t thread process will be more

However, I found that it was not the case. I tried with t=10. And still it is faster than the 2 thread process. For eg. if I have to do 10,000,000 iterations, with the two thread process I will have the 2 threads do iterations for 5,000,000 so that we have a total of 
10,000,000 iterations. If I have to do with the 10 thread process, I will let each thread do iterations for 1,000,000 so that we have a total of 10,000,000 as well.

I was expecting the 10 thread process to consume more time. But it's not the case. Is there any bug in the code? It looks fine to me

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense ... You first state that you think it should take longer to split the task among N threads, and then you say that it was faster to split the task.  Then you repeat your initial hypothesis that it was faster with a single thread.  It has to be either/or, not both ...

Comment: No, I didn't say that. I said that it always took longer time when I used a single thread rather than dividing the work into multiple threads

Comment: If your hardware permits it, the threads run in parallel. Then of course it takes less time if two threads each do half as much work in parallel than if one does it all.

Comment: You do not mention the exact type of CPU that you are using... Mentioning your OS would also make sense, since not all systems use the same scheduling algorithms...

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the code. Why do you think it should be running slower with 10 threads? Try 32 or 64 and then you will probably see a degradation.

Comment: @user12331: which CPU are you using? Which kernel version?

Comment: My CPU is Intel core 2duo, 2.4GHz and my kernel version is Linux version 3.0.0-12-generic(Buildd@crested)

Comment: You may want to post the details on exactly how you're building this benchmark program (ie., what compiler options are in effect) and details on the runs.  There can be a lot of devil in the details with simple benchmarks.

Comment: I build it simply like gcc myfile.c -o myfile -lpthread. Then I run the program like ./myfile 2 5000000 and ./myfile 10 1000000. As you can see the total number of iterations in both cases is same. However, the number of threads are different and the number of iterations done by each thread in the two cases is different. But the total is the same i.e, the same amount of work is done. However, because of time slicing I am expecting the one with greater number of threads to be slow comparatively.

Comment: As far as I know the program is fine. Can anyone try the above code in their computer and let me know if they get different results. I mean running with 2 threads and 5000000 iterations for each thread(First case) and running with 10 threads and 1000000 iterations for each thread(Second case). What do you get?

Comment: @Tudor I tried with 32 and more threads but still it is better than running with 2 threads, Time slicing isn't showing any effect even when I use huge number of threads

Comment: Why did you edit out the code?

Comment: @user12331: Ok try a huge number, say 256-512.

Comment: @Tudor I tried with even 1000 threads but still it is not different. I can't see any difference. It is almost always better than with 2 threads

Comment: @Tudor the issue is the larger number of thread version is almost always better than the 2 thread version. I don't seem to figure that out. Can anyone try the above code and let me know what they observe?

Comment: Are you sure ? I ran you code and for more threads I got more usage time !

Comment: How much did you get? Can you give some information. How did you calculate the usage time?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing 10000000 (10 million) x 1000 iterations sequentially and 5000000 (5 million) x 1000 iterations for each thread in the parallel version. In my experience that's more than enough work to make the startup overhead insignificant. The results seem correct to me.

With 2 cores and 2 threads there is no timeslicing involved (at least among the 2 worker threads), as the scheduler is smart enough to put the threads on separate cores and keep them there.

In order to see some degradation you need to move some memory around through the caches, such that each context switch actually penalizes the performance by causing some data to be evicted from the caches. Here's the running times I'm getting:

> ./a.out 2 500000000 
>   Number of threads = 2 
>   Number of iterations in each thread = 250000000 
>  
>   Total time taken = 5.931148 
>   ./a.out 1000 500000000 
>   Number of threads = 1000 
>   Number of iterations in each thread = 500000 
>   Total time taken = 6.563666 
>   ./a.out 2000 500000000 
>   Number of threads = 2000 
>   Number of iterations in each thread = 250000 
>   Total time taken = 7.087449

And here's the code. I'm basically partitioning a large array among the given threads and squaring every item in the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

long* array;
int length;
int threads;

void *tfunc(void *arg) {
  int n = (int)arg;
  int i;
  int j;
  int x;
  long sum = 0;
  //printf("%d\n",*n);
  int start = n * (length / threads);
  int end = (n + 1) * (length / threads);

  for (i=start; i<end; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i] * array[i];
    //printf("%d\n",i);
  }
  return(0);

}

double timestamp() {
  struct timeval tp;
  gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
  return (double)tp.tv_sec + tp.tv_usec / 1000000.;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int numberOfIterations = atoi(argv[2]);
  int numberOfThreads = atoi(argv[1]);
  int i;
  printf("Number of threads = %d\n",numberOfThreads);
  printf("Number of iterations in each thread = %d \n", numberOfIterations / numberOfThreads);
  pthread_t workerThreads[numberOfThreads];
  int *arg = &numberOfIterations;

  array = (long*)malloc(numberOfIterations * sizeof(long));
  length = numberOfIterations;
  threads = numberOfThreads;
  int result[numberOfThreads];

  double timeTaken;
  timeTaken = timestamp();

  for(i=0; i<numberOfThreads; i++) {
    result[i] = pthread_create(workerThreads+i, NULL, tfunc, (void*)i);
  }

  for(i=0; i<numberOfThreads; i++) {
    pthread_join(workerThreads[i], NULL);
  }

  timeTaken = timestamp() - timeTaken;
  printf("Total time taken = %f\n", timeTaken);
  /*printf("The results are\n");
  for(i=0; i<numberOfThreads; i++) {
    printf("%d\n",result[i]);
  }*/

  free(array);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I have even tried using processes instead of threads because context switching for processes is more than for threads. However, still if I use 20 threads to do 1/20 of the work each, it takes less time than using 2 threads doing 1/2 of the work. Is there any bug in the code

Comment: I cannot get how your program compiled. I mean int n = (int)arg;
Doesn't this line show any error. I mean. You are casting from pointer to an integer. It shows error when I try to compile

Comment: I cannot get how your program compiled. I mean int n = (int)arg; Doesn't this line show any error. I mean. You are casting from pointer to an integer. It shows error when I try to compile

Comment: @user12331: @user12331: I only get a warning. Are you on a 64 bit system? In that case you're probably getting the "loses precision..." error. You could try to just use a long for `i` and `n` instead, since the size matches a pointer and then cast it back to int since there is no problem of losing precision.

Comment: I get the following error------ warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

Comment: Your results, too, are just about what I would have expected <g>

Answer (score 1):

For an app to demonstrate a significant, easily-measurable slowdown with many more threads than processors, you have to work at it:

1) The threads must be CPU-intensive, ie. not block on I/O or each other.  If you are using a simple counting loop, (as it sounds like you are), then yes, that's done.

2) You have to arrange each thread to work on data that is large enough so that the L1 cache requires significant flushing upon a context-swap.  If you just increment one integer, this flushing will not happen and the context-switch overhead will be too small, (compared with the interval between timer-driven scheduling runs), to easily demonstrate.

Windows example data, minimal cache-flushing, i7, 4/8 cores:

```
8 tests,
400 tasks,
counting to 10000000,
using 8 threads:
Ticks: 2199
Ticks: 2184
Ticks: 2215
Ticks: 2153
Ticks: 2200
Ticks: 2215
Ticks: 2200
Ticks: 2230
Average: 2199 ms

8 tests,
400 tasks,
counting to 10000000,
using 32 threads:
Ticks: 2137
Ticks: 2121
Ticks: 2153
Ticks: 2138
Ticks: 2137
Ticks: 2121
Ticks: 2153
Ticks: 2137
Average: 2137 ms

8 tests,
400 tasks,
counting to 10000000,
using 128 threads:
Ticks: 2168
Ticks: 2106
Ticks: 2184
Ticks: 2106
Ticks: 2137
Ticks: 2122
Ticks: 2106
Ticks: 2137
Average: 2133 ms

8 tests,
400 tasks,
counting to 10000000,
using 400 threads:
Ticks: 2137
Ticks: 2153
Ticks: 2059
Ticks: 2153
Ticks: 2168
Ticks: 2122
Ticks: 2168
Ticks: 2138
Average: 2137 ms
```

Comment: Your results are very similar to mine. I also did not see any degradation even with huge numbers of threads (10000). Most likely, as you said, there needs to be cache flushing when context switches occur, otherwise they're basically free.

Answer (score 0):

How many CPU cores do you have on your machine?  The thing about CPU bound threads is that even though there may be overhead for setting up and scheduling the threads that doesn't exist when you have only a single thread, if those threads can actually execute at the same time (instead of just appearing to execute at the the same time) then the threads can still produce a gain that's greater than the overhead costs.

Comment: I have just 2 cores in my case. But still if I use like 20 threads or more it should have shown decrease in performance or say consumed more time. But in my case it is always better to use multiple threads even as much as 20

Comment: The compiler may be optimizing your loop away.

Comment: I curious - how does 20 threads compare to 2 threads or 4 threads?

Comment: I meant to say if I use 20 threads so that each thread has 1/20 of the work to be done. And I have 2 threads with each thread having 1/2 of the work to be done. Then because of context switching 20 threads should be slower than 2 threads isn't it? considering I have two processors

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple logical cores, your threads will execute in parallel.

To test your hypothesis, you need to pin them to a single logical core.

Comment: Since I have two cores, I have tried comparing using 2 threads vs 20 threads. However, the results are not consistent. Sometimes, when I use 2 threads it is better than using 20 threads and sometimes when I use 20 threads it is better than 2 threads. I varied the length of the task in between. So my issue is when I vary the task, and compare 2 vs 20 threads the results are not consistent